# Fatal error in multishop Zend Cache.php

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0

I get the following error in my shop, after it had worked normally:

> Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Cache_Core' not found in /public_html/lib/Zend/Cache.php on line 195

It breaks the entire website, and I have no idea why, as it happened without any lead.

All folders have been given 777 permission, to make sure that wasn't the problem.

Any idea where I should look for this?

Comment: does `/public_html/lib/Zend/Cache/Core.php` exist?

Comment: Yes, it does exist.

Comment: php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your permissions for files as well as folders (http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_filesystem_permissions).  Also, clear your /var/cache/ and /var/sessions/ folders.  If you've enable compilation, disable it, and cycle your cache from within the admin system if you can access it.

Comment: I will accept your answer, even though it wasn't the solution. With similar problems this will almost always solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a full server, making several files half empty or non-existant.